# Pandas: group by quantiles and calculate stats

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, quantile

I have the yearly income data of 99 people:

```
import pandas, random
incomes = pandas.DataFrame({'income':[round(random.triangular(20,80,200),0) for i in range(99)]})
```

How to:

- group them in 3 quantiles, "poor", "middle", "rich", each of 33 people
- calculate the average income of each quantile

Sorry, sounds like a newbie question. I'm learning. Thank you!

Comment: The quantiles might not perfectly be 33/33/33, especially with integers

Comment: thanks @yatu ! I upvoted you, but did not "accept" your answer as final, as I still have the that qcut() splits the set unevenly, in presence of duplicates at bin edges

Answer (score 6):

To group the column as mentioned, you can use [`Series.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html), which allows to specify a sequence of quantiles. Then use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to split the column in bins.

You can then use the "quantile groups" to obtain statistics grouping the dataframe as bellow:

```
quant = incomes.income.quantile(q=[0,0.33,0.66,1]).values
incomes['groups'] = pd.cut(incomes.income, quant, labels=["poor", "middle", "rich"])
incomes['avg_income'] = incomes.groupby('groups').transform('mean')
```

Or, as @allolz mentions, you can use `qcut` which allows for doing the above in a single step:

```
incomes['groups'] = pd.qcut(incomes.income, 3, labels=['poor', 'medium', 'rich'])
```

---

```
print(incomes)

    income  groups  avg_income
0     96.0  middle   89.312500
1     77.0    poor   53.531250
2     93.0  middle   89.312500
3     86.0  middle   89.312500
4     59.0    poor   53.531250
..     ...     ...         ...
94    29.0    poor   53.531250
95   121.0    rich  112.823529
96    87.0  middle   89.312500
97   111.0    rich  112.823529
98    55.0    poor   53.531250
```

Comment: thanks @yatu, I still have the issue that qcut() does not split bins evenly in presence of duplicates. The only workaround I could think of was to add an extra "rank" column that has unique values, and use that "rank" column for the qcut(). But I hope there is a more straightforward solution...

Comment: tbh I was thinking of something on the lines of that @elemolotiv Not any straightforward solution that I'm aware of unfortunately